# Resize the image using PHP vips library

Tags: vips

I am using both PHP imagick and PHP vips library for image operations. I am working on image resize operation. For imagick I am using resizeImage() function and for vips I am using resize() function. But the output of both the image are different for same height and width. I want to same output for vips. Here I add my code which I am using for vips. I want same result for vips also, which I got into imagick

```
<!-- Imagick Code -->
$img = new Imagick($ipFile); 
$img->resizeImage(1000, 1000, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, true);
$img->writeimage($opFile);

<!-- VIPS Code -->
$im = Vips\Image::newFromFile($ipFile);
$im = $im->resize($ratio, ['kernel' => 'lanczos2']);
$im->writeToFile($opFile);
```

Vips Output file:
[image: Vips Output file]
Imagick Output file:
[image: Imagick Output file]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `resize` with php-vips unless you really have to. You'll get better quality, better speed and lower memory use with `thumbnail`.

The `thumbnail` operation combines load and resize in one, so it can exploit tricks like shrink-on-load. It knows about transparency, so it'll resize PNGs correctly. It also knows about vector formats like PDF and SVG and will size them in the best way.

Try:

```php
<!-- VIPS Code -->
$im = Vips\Image::thumbnail($ipFile, 1000);
$im->writeToFile($opFile);
```

Benchmark:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e convert ~/pics/nina.jpg -resize 1000x1000 x.jpg
238836:0.77
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e vips resize ~/pics/nina.jpg x.jpg .1653439153
60996:0.39
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e vips thumbnail ~/pics/nina.jpg x.jpg 1000
49148:0.16
```

`nina.jpg` is a 6k x 4k RGB JPG image.

- imagick resizes in 770ms and 240MB of memory
- vips `resize` takes 390ms and 61MB of memory
- vips `thumbnail` takes 160ms and 50MB of memory

Quality will be the same in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Need one more help imagick provide Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS for apply filter and also there is one blur option in resize option how can i achieve that using vips?

Comment: libvips `thumbnail` uses lanczos3.

Comment: Is there any way for change lanczos3?

Comment: `thumbnail` is supposed to implement best practice, so there are very few options. Why do you need a different kernel?

Comment: Little bit confused about filters now got the idea and i don't need to change kernel. Thank you for the help

Comment: One more thing, Imagick::getImageBlob() function is an inbuilt function in PHP which is used to get the image sequence as a blob. I want to do same for vips any similar method for that?

Comment: Yes, `$str = $image->writeToBuffer('.jpg');`, see https://libvips.github.io/php-vips/docs/classes/Jcupitt-Vips-Image.html#method_writeToBuffer

Comment: I am crooping the image by using below php vips method
$im = $im->crop(87, 98, 530, 352);
I am getting an error bad extract area, don'r know why that error occurred. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: It's `crop(left, top, width, height)`. You are asking for an area outside the image edges.